# User undefined for RBAC in NestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, server, nestjs, backend

roles.guard.ts:

```
    import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
    import { Role } from './role.enum';
    import { ROLES_KEY } from './roles.decorator';


    @Injectable()
    export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
      constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}

      canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
        const requiredRoles = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<Role[]>(ROLES_KEY, [
          context.getHandler(),
          context.getClass(),
        ]);

        if (!requiredRoles) {
          return true;
        }

        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const user = request?.user;
        console.log('User:', user);

        if (!user || !user.roles || !Array.isArray(user.roles)) {
          return false; 
        }

        return requiredRoles.some((role) => user.roles.includes(role));
      }
    }
```

I'm trying to implement RBAC using NestJS.. i followed every instructions from the documentations.. But the function cant check for roles since the user from Request is undefined.. I have been following the official NestJS documentations..

I checked several forums but none of them are giving a proper answer.